# Can JSForce be used in a public site without login?

Tags: force.com-sites, jsforce

I want to build a public Salesforce site where I can share my SF Accounts' details with the public without forcing them to login (I know this can be achieved with a controller/ JavaScript Remoting).

I tried looking for a tutorial but could not find one without a login. Is this even possible with JSForce?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSforce calls the Salesforce Rest Endpoints to get and post data. The basic requirement to use Salesforce Rest Endpoint is to get API enabled Session-Id.

JSForce uses your username/password to get the session id using username/password [flow](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/intro_understanding_username_password_oauth_flow.htm?search_text=Session).

So in JS force, if you provide Username and Password of Salesforce User which is API enabled you will be able to use it.

But.......
JSforce gets the Authentication in [Javascript](https://jsforce.github.io/).  Which means you have to expose the username and password on a public facing site. Which according to me is very very hacky and prone to attacks.